# Firebase Use Policy Implementation

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-analytics

I'm developing Android application which is using Firebase concretely Analytics and Crash Reporting.

Application will be free and it will be used by small group of people but I want to publish it on Google Play store.

I have read [this terms](https://firebase.google.com/policies/analytics), but I'm still little disappointed and scared about implementation of Firebase Use Policy handle.

My questions:

- What I need to implement to handle use policy?
- Should I implement confirmation dialog at the first start of app or it could be implemented as button for dialog in about app screen?
- What text should be inside?

Thank you for your responses.

Answer (score 2):

If you are collecting data to show your own advertising is not allowed as I understand. Also, if you are going to use the data collected for third parties, you should ask the user if they agree to share this information or not. You could put a clause where you say that if you continue to use the application you are accepting the terms and conditions of the app

You are required to notify your App Users by disclosing the following information:

- The Firebase Analytics features you have implemented.
- How you and third-party vendors use first-party cookies, or other first-party identifiers, and third-party cookies and similar technologies, such as identifiers for mobile devices (including Android Advertising ID and Advertising Identifier for iOS), or other third-party identifiers, together.
- How App Users can opt-out of the Firebase Analytics features you use, including through applicable device settings, such as the device advertising settings for mobile apps, or any other available means.

It depends on the context of the application to tell you that it would go in the clause of use and collection of Google analytics . You just have to write what you are doing with the data and for which you will use them.